# Docker container not copying certificate

Tags: docker, go

I want to run a https server using docker, I cannot seem to get the certificate to copy across

I want to use a bind mount so I don't have to restart the server whenever I renew the ssl certificate

Docker does not work when I use the command I'll list below

In my linux machine there is fullchain.pem and privkey.pem inside:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/
```

My code is as such:

```golang
    go func() {
        err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443",
            "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem",
            "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem",
            r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        }
    }()
```

When I run the docker command:

```
docker run  -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain -p 443:443 -p 80:80 imagehere
```

I get this:

```
2022/11/20 12:28:32 ListenAndServe: open /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the files in the container when running something like `ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/` from within the container?

Comment: I added an answer as I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to fix it

For some reason, due to write permissions, read perms, etc it didn't work unless I moved the certificates to my home directory

So I just moved the certs to ~/cert and repeated the docker command binding ~/cert to ... and it worked.

I believe this is due to certbot using 0700 permissions for certificates, not due to the directory. So docker cannot read the files

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions in answers. --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I believe this is due to certbot using 0700 permissions for certificates, not due to the directory. So docker cannot read the files